# Meaning of 'general case'

Tags: game-theory

I was working on this problem (part a) and I was wondering what is meant by the term 'the general case'. Does this mean just make assumptions c>0 and v>0 then just solve? or should i approach it as 'find all NE for different cases such as when v>c, c>v, c=v) [image: attached question]

Answer (score 2):

By the "*general case*" they probably mean that there are no restrictions on the parameters at all, so in (a) you should not make the usual assumptions that $c > v > 0$ or $v_1=v_2$, $c_1 = c_2$.

To be sure, you can ask a peer/your TA/your professor, this is a valid question.

Comment: If i can't make the assumption that c>0 however, how will i know if the payoff for (H,H) is less than the payoffs for (D,D). I'm not sure how would i would calculate each players best response without this assumption?

Comment: @dreadpirateroberts You would have to talk about NE case by case. Do ask your TA though.